# Навигация Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, навигация

Всем привет!

Бьюсь уже неделю... Прошу помощи.

Обычный стандартный проект Xamarin forms. Главная страница - tabbedpage (ну тип такой, все знают). И есть еще одна страница tabbedpage.

Объясните как правильно сделать переход с первой на вторую, пожалуйста. Метод

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MySecondTabbedPage())
```

вызывает вторую страницу, но верхнее и нижнее меню задваиваются... Т.е. показывается меню и первой страницы и второй.

Как показать меню только второй страницы???

Верхнем меню я называю то место сверху где появляется кнопка "назад", нижним - там где ссылки на дочерние страницы.

Пробовал использовать метод:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MySecondTabbedPage())
```

тогда все хорошо (меню не задваиваются) но НЕТ КНОПКИ НАЗАД... А это принципиально важно.

Спасибо, за помощь.

Comment: Возможно не в тему, но если вы вызываете `async` метод, то где-то должен быть `await`.

Answer (score 1):

`App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MySecondTabbedPage())` эквивалентно `App.Current.MainPage = new MySecondTabbedPage()` - мы просто меняем MainPage.

в любой из [страниц](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/) есть [NavigationStack](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical), с которым можно работать при помощи `Navigation.PushAsync` и `Navigation.PopAsync`. при Push xamarin будет накидывать страницу "поверх" текущей, по кнопке "назад" или Pop - убирать страницу. работает как колода карт.

TabbedPage в целом не задумывалась для использования в качестве навигационной страницы. TabbedPage - это Page, которая содержит ***коллекцию страниц***. если у Вас главная - TabbedPage, а Вы хотите ***в её NavigationStack*** накинуть страницу, то в Push обычно передают не экзамеляр TabbedPage, а ContentPage. тогда xamarin создаст NavigationPage с кнопкой "назад", но не будет вкладок/табов. однако если ***из находящейся в коллекции страницы*** вызвать Push c ContentPage в качестве аргумента, возможно вы получите необходимое (или Push с TabbedPage изнутри основной TabbedPage). но это слегка tricky.

если нужны табы в NavigationPage, или кнопка "назад" в TabbedPage , можно [встроить в NavigationBar вьюху](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#displaying-views-in-the-navigation-bar).

если в одном приложении есть потребность в нескольких страницах с табами, возможно стоит рассмотреть MasterDetailPage, она позволяет добавить всплывающее меню слева, и это будет непротиворечиво с точки зрения UX (хотя я тут не эксперт). [вот пример](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.commit451.gitlab). либо свой кастомный ContentPage cо своим кастомным TabbedView и пушить его NavigationStack. вариантов масса